# Social Media Sharing on custom query page

Tags: social-media

I am getting custom posts on a page, and used add to any sharing plugin, the problem is that the plugin is sharing the page url instead of post url.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by passing the permalink in shortcode..